# Bulk data storage in iOS and Android (10GB plus)

Tags: android, database, networking, ios6

I have a general question as to what amount of data can we store in **iOS** and **Android**. My app would be storing nearly about 10GB plus data.

Is there any way to do this? The data will persist only for a period of maximum one day. The user will collect the data and save it on DB located on server. But if there is network error the data might get lost. So I'm taking this precaution to save data locally and then divide the packets in 10MB (or whatever) each and then start Data Transfer. So that even if one packet is lost I can start over.

Also can we have this packet thing in iOS and Android.

Comment: What do you have (tried) so far?

Comment: @ChristianGärtner I googled about storing  the data in the application directory but then it will not support this Bulk Data at the same time.Some one recommended me to store it on server but then the Client wont approve it for obvious reasons : Cost

Answer (score 0):

On Android you could use **ExternalStorage**. You can use all the *SD/External* memory you need. [Here is the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Comment: What if the user does not have a SD Card (Usually cellphone's done come with these days) and moreover if the internal memory is not large enough ???

Comment: ExternalStorage in Android doesn't have to be an SD Card. For example, lots of Nexus, HTC or Samsung devices don't have SD Cards but getExternalStorageDirectory() will return a File with the path to that external memory (16/32GB). More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html